# Equivalent of a local limit theorem in the large deviation region and asymptotics of a convolution operator

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, semigroups-of-operators, convolution, large-deviations

Let $\{X_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables satisfying $\mathbb{E} X_1 = 0$ and $\mathbb{E} X_1 ^2 < \infty$. Assume that $\{S_n  \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a non-lattice random walk, where $S_n = X_1+...+ X_n$. I am wondering whether there is a 'local large deviation theorem' running along these lines:

**Theorem.** *Let $0 < a < b$. Then as $n \to \infty$ uniformly for $r \in [an, bn]$*
$$
 \mathbb{P} \{  S_n \in [r,r+1] \} \sim \int\limits_{r} ^{r+1} \kappa _n (x) dx,
$$
*where $\kappa _n$ is a function given explicitly.*

Similar results are available for $r = o(n)$ in [1], at least for absolutely continuous random variables. This question can also be formulated in terms of the associated convolution operator. Let $a \in L^1$, $a \geq 0$. Define the operator $L$ on some function space by
$$
Lu (x) = \int\limits _{\mathbb{R}} u(y)a(x-y) dy
$$
and set $u_n = L ^n \delta _0$ (or alternatively $u_n = \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon}L ^n \mathbf{1} _\varepsilon$, where $\mathbf{1} _\varepsilon$ is the indicator of $[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]$ for a small $\varepsilon > 0$). What can  we say about
$$
\int\limits _{r} ^{r+1} u_n (x)dx.
$$
for $r \in [an, bn]$, possibly under some additional assumptions on $a$?

[1]: Richter, W. (1957). Local limit theorems for large deviations. Theory of Probability & Its Applications, 2(2), 206-220.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general classes of bounded pdf's of $X_1$, including pdf's with exponential-like, super-exponential, and sub-exponential tails, your Theorem follows from the considerations in [Sections 2.1 and 2.2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/009630039490197X), with
$$\kappa_n(x)=p_{S_n}(r)e^{-s_0(x-r)},$$
where $p_{S_n}$ is the pdf of $S_n$,
$$s_0:=\sup\{s\ge0\colon m(s)<r/n\},$$
and
$$m(s):=\frac{EX_1e^{sX_1}}{Ee^{sX_1}}.$$
As can also be seen from those considerations, the asymptotics of $p_{S_n}(r)$ will very much depend on how heavy the right tail of the distribution of $X_1$ is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think $\kappa _n$ that I am looking for is contained in (2.15) of the paper that you link. The expression for $\kappa _n$ given in the answer is a little bit unsatisfactory because the question is basically about the density $p_{S_n}$, so the answer should not contain it (otherwise we could take $\kappa _n(x) = p_{S_n}(x)$).

Comment: You are right. However, as stated in the answer, "the asymptotics of $p_{S_n}(r)$ will very much depend on how heavy the right tail of the distribution of $X_1$ is". When the tail is exponential-like or lighter than that, then (2.15) is indeed an answer. For tails heavier than exponential and varying regularly enough, one can use results due to A. Nagaev cited in the linked paper.